# Jquery, ajax: Clicking on a button and getting the value of the cell next to it on the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have been reading the tutorials on JS and it occurred to me that I wanted the following:

Say a table with 3 cols and several rows.

First col an int value, second colon a yes green button and third a red button

On clicking on the button, it should get as value that of the cells of the first colum (I am doing a polling table).

UPDATE IV:

This works finally, thanks to Adeneo and Anthony Grist. Thank you for your patience and help.

Here it is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.oui').click(function(){
            var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
            $(this).attr('value', valor);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Prenom</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Tantieme</th>
                        <th>Oui</th>    
                        <th>Non</th>
                        <th>Abstention</th>    
                        <th>Absent</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($polls as $vote)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $vote->prenom}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $vote->nom}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $vote->tantieme }}</td>
                        <td><button type="button" id="oui" class="btn btn-success">VOTE OUI</button></td>    
                        <td><button type="button" id="non" class="btn btn-danger">VOTE NON</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">ABSTENTION</button></td>    
                        <td><button type="button" id="default" value = "230" class="btn btn-default">ABSENT</button></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML.

Comment: It doesn't really sound complicated at all, but we need to see the markup, not some javascript that has nothing to do with the issue. I'm guessing you want something like `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()`

Comment: Seeing the markup, the line of jQuery I posted above should work just fine inside the `change()` function as long as you pass `this` as an argument, or even better, remove the inline javascript.

Comment: Are you using `Angular`?

Comment: no, I am using Laravel

Comment: I have tried it as edited above, will probably be my fault but I am not getting it to work sorry

Comment: As noted, `this` isn't the element when you're using inline javascript like that, you have to change the function call to `onclick="change(this)"` then use that argument in the function `function change(elem) { $(elem).closest('tr').rest_goes_here ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been reading the tutorials on JS and it occurred to me that I wanted the following:

Say a table with 3 cols and several rows.

First col an int value, second colon a yes green button and third a red button

On clicking on the button, it should get as value that of the cells of the first colum (I am doing a polling table).

UPDATE IV:

This works finally, thanks to Adeneo and Anthony Grist. Thank you for your patience and help.

Here it is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.oui').click(function(){
            var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
            $(this).attr('value', valor);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Prenom</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Tantieme</th>
                        <th>Oui</th>    
                        <th>Non</th>
                        <th>Abstention</th>    
                        <th>Absent</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($polls as $vote)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $vote->prenom}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $vote->nom}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $vote->tantieme }}</td>
                        <td><button type="button" id="oui" class="btn btn-success">VOTE OUI</button></td>    
                        <td><button type="button" id="non" class="btn btn-danger">VOTE NON</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">ABSTENTION</button></td>    
                        <td><button type="button" id="default" value = "230" class="btn btn-default">ABSENT</button></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It only works for the first row because you're trying to re-use IDs. They're supposed to be a **unique** identifier to a single specific element.

Comment: yes, you are correct!, how should I bypass that problem? I tried replacing it with 'this' but did not come on

Comment: Change from `id="oui"` to `class="oui"` in your HTML, change the selector to `$('.oui').click(...);`, then use `$(this)` inside the click event handler function to refer to the one that was actually clicked on.

Comment: sort of this?:                                                       
$(document).ready(function(){                                        

 $('.oui').click(function(this){
        
var valor = $('.oui').closest('tr').find('td:first').text();         
$('.oui').attr('value', valor);
 });
});
    </script>

Comment: Close. `.click(function(event) { var valor = $(this).closest(...);});`.

Comment: hmm, it extends the value to all rows. Each row is a different vote by a different person. If the first row marks 100, the all rows below are marking also 100. Each row should be independent from someone else's row

Comment: Are you using `$(this)` *everywhere* you previously used `$('#oui')` in the event handler?

Comment: No, like this:    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.oui').click(function(event){
        
var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
$('.oui').attr('value', valor);
 });
});
    </script>